# Java if (Yes or No Statement)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hey there I got into some trouble with my java Code.
I try to code a bit around with java for a few hours and I dont know much thats why im asking. I learn best by trying but I get into so many problems.

So: I want the scanner to scan the next Statement and if its "ja" it should do the if thing etc.

The problem is, when i try to compile it it has an error with the = s.nextInt thing. In the console it says: "cannot find symbole". I tried so many things I dont know what to do. Allready tried so much.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Brotcrunsher {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Hallo");
        System.out.println ("A flag has more then 1 color right?");
        String a = s.NextInt();
        if (a.equals("ja")) {
            System.out.println ("You arent dumb, nice.");
        } // end of if
        else {
            System.out.println ("You arentn a genie");
        } // end of if-else
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem solved. Thank you for every awnser. I try my best to Tag my posts better and to format my code better

Comment: Try `scan.nextLine()` instead of `s.NextInt()`

Comment: first, it is `nextInt` not `NextInt` (explaining the "cannot find symbol") and of course this is used to get an `int` not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
String a = s.NextInt();
```

You want `a` to be String (which makes sense, as you want to compare it against other Strings later on); so you better use:

```
String a = s.nextLine();
```

instead!

The other method a) does not exist and b) `nextInt()` ... returns a number, not a string

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However there hasn't been big changed in the console. For some reason it still says: the following:

"String a = s.nextLine ();
                  ^

symbol: method nextLine ()
location: class Brotcrusher


Error: cannot find symbole

Comment: @Kaipo It is named `scan` in the declaration...  you made a typo in your code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Brotcrunsher {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Hallo");
        System.out.println ("A flag has more then 1 color right?");

        String a = scan.nextLine();
        if (a.equals("ja")) {
            System.out.println ("You arent dumb, nice.");
        } // end of if
        else {
            System.out.println ("You arentn a genie");
        } // end of if-else
    }
}
```

Comment: you should highlight the changes in this kind of answer, without this, he will never see the differences and simply copy-past ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can see two errors, firstly you are taking a string input from the command line user so your scanner must be *"scanner.nextLine()"* which takes a string, as it stands you are expecting an integer value.

Second your *"s.scanner"* is not calling anything, you have declared your scanner with the name *"scan"*, so you need to change that to *"scan"*.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("A flag has more than one colour?");
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    if (input.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("well done");
    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, one is `a` is a `String` not an `int` and the second is [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) (or [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) or [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--)). And, the local reference is `scan` (not `s`). Like,

```
String a = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ScannerTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your rollno");
        int rollno=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String name=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your fee");
        double fee=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Rollno:"+rollno+" name:"+name+" fee:"+fee);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

refrence: http://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class

Comment: Because that link contain entire example

Comment: Just one of the important line of the page I point : _"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."_ This looks like a comment for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have got a compilation error that should be

```
String a = scan.next();
```

Since scan is your scanner object where you are using `String a = s.NextInt();` which is not at all an object of scanner.